# New certificate mime types from Tika not on official list

Tags: java, apache-tika

We recently updated tika from 1.24 to 1.27 and noticed that mime types detected by tika for some certificate files changed:

- for .cer file we used to get `application/x-x509-ca-cert` and now we get `application/x-x509-cert; format=der`
- for .pem file we used to get `text/plain` and now we get `application/x-x509-key; format=pem`
- for .crt file we used to get `application/x-x509-ca-cert` and now we get `application/x-x509-cert; format=pem`

The problem is that none of the new mime types can be found in the [official list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). Are these new types supposed to be added to the official list or shall we treat them as erroneous?

Comment: Nothing with a `x-` prefix is official, it is what is used for ones that aren't registered yet

Comment: @Gagravarr: that's been the rule, but [8894 made an exception](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8894.html#name-registration-of-the-applica). However, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119284/does-certificate-file-types-can-be-detected-using-tika points to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3205 which doesn't indicate any official source for x-x509-{cert,key} -- and most of the key-files detected are OpenSSL 'traditional' formats which were never standardized and I doubt they will be now (plus if you're sending a key-file over http or email your system is probably breached).

Comment: There's no official source for the `x-` prefixes, that's kinda the point... For Tika we just looked at what other systems were already using and based ours on that